# Core Data: Fetch via specific property (join relationship)

Tags: iphone, macos, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have an core data model as follows

[image]

The `attributes` property of `Page` is a set of `DictionaryEntry`, they are values for my Page objects, much like a standard `NSDictionary` (except all of the `keys` and `values` are strings)

I have a `Page` that has a `DictionaryEntry` with `key="title"` and `value="Home"`. How would i form a fetch request to load that specific page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have a look at the predicate syntax for subqueries. You can not use the usual ANY keyword as this only allows you to match one column not two at the same time.

```
  NSString *keyValue = @"title";
  NSString *valueValue = @"home";

  NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Page" inManagedObjectContext:_context]];
  [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(attributes, $a, $a.key == %@ && $a.value == %@).@count != 0)", keyValue, valueValue]];
```

The simpler predicate `ANY attributes.key = "title" AND ANY attributes.value = "home"` would not work as it also returns pages that have two dicts e.g. key='addr'/value='home' and key='title'/value='pete'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you start by knowing the "key" to the DictionaryEntry of "Title".

Why don't create an NSFetchRequest on the DictionaryEntry object using  your known "key" when you create an NSPredicate.

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DictionaryEntry" inManagedObjectContext:_context]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key == %@", keyValue]];
```

Once you have your valid DictionaryEntry object, you can then use your CoreData crufted up "page" relationship to get your valid Page.