# NSPredicate multiple ANY query with CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to find all instances of an object that contain a reference to a combination of separate objects in my object graph.

```
recommendation
```

*may* contain one or more of the following three objects:

```
damageType

areaDamaged

validVehicles
```

This structure is built from an import of an existing system's file format and I am unable to restructure the object graph.

I'm using an `NSPredicate` to find all `recommendation` objects that have a `damageType` matching a selected damage as follows:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestDamages = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Recommendation class])];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY damageType == %@", _currentRecordedDamage.damageType];
```

But want the filter to return all `Recommendations` that have matches for a specific `damageType`, `areaDamaged` and `validVehicle`

I've tried

```
NSMutableArray *predicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY damageType == %@", _currentRecordedDamage.damageType];
        [predicates addObject:predicate];
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY areaDamaged == %@", _currentAreaDamaged];
        [predicates addObject:predicate2];
NSPredicate *predicate3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY validVehicles == %@", _currentVehicle];
        [predicates addObject:predicate3];


fetchRequestDamages.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];


fetchRequestDamages.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]];

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequestDamages managedObjectContext:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

NSError *error;

[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
 int resultsFound = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count;
```

but it seems this returns the set of all objects satisfying any of the predicates - I'd like the set of objects that match all three.

I'm looking into using `SUBQUERY` but can't quite make sense of how to create this query?

Comment: What's your code for executing the fetch request?

Comment: @davbryn: So you do already what I suggested below. - Perhaps you can show an example of what you get currently and what you expect.

Comment: Are damageType and areaDamaged and validVehicles to-many relationships from recommendation? If not simply go with AndrewShmigs. If they are then you will need SubQueries.

Comment: @FelixLam yes, they are all to-many

Comment: Maybe have a look at the response I gave here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725936/core-data-fetch-via-specific-property-join-relationship/3745585#3745585

Comment: A SUBQUERY helps if you have a single to-many relationship and you want to test several attributes of the related objects. Here (if I see it correctly) you have three different to-many relationships where each related object has a single attribute to check.

Comment: @MartinR that does sound like it makes a lot of sense, when you compare the adapted code example below it looks overly complicated and too simple compared to the original answer i linked to above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just combine the three predicates with "AND" to find the objects that match all of them:

```
NSArray *predicates = ... // your array of predicates
NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
[fetchRequestDamages setPredicate:finalPredicate];
```

Comment: When I have the three AND predicates it returns a set that contains recommendations that don't have a validVehicle match in it's set (but does have a match for another property).

Comment: @davbryn: That is strange. It should return only objects that satisfy all three sub-predicates. - Have you tested all three predicates separately?

Comment: Is that not what he does in his code? `fetchRequestDamages.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];`

Comment: @FelixLam: Yes, but I knew that only after he updated the question with this information.

Comment: This answer is correct - the problem (regrettably) was that the predicates all matched as they should - there was an importer error that was linking the object to all three requirements. I spotted it by running the predicates individually and investigating the relationships

Answer (score 2):

Why not to use AND in one query?
Something like:

```
damage = %@ AND damagePoints = %@ AND damageCost = %@
```

and:

```
damageType IN %@
```

Where %@ in the last code example should be an array/set or something else.

Comment: Much neater to use a compound predicate

Comment: @DavidCaunt, if you have 2-3 statements - its ok to use all-in-one, otherwise you definitely should use compound predicates.